# Cannot access local shared library from /usr/local/lib

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm venturing into the world of C++ and Linux, and am having problems linking against a shared library.

I have a library, `libicuuc.so.44.1`, installed in `/usr/local/lib`. There is also a link in the same directory, `libicuuc.so.44` pointing to that library.

My `/etc/ld.so.conf` reads:

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

I have a file, `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf`, that contains:

```
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
```

However, when I compile my program (that includes `LIBS += -licuuc`), I get the following error at runtime:

> error while loading shared libraries:
>   libicuuc.so.44: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

I am using Qt Creator on Ubuntu 10.04.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you modify by yourself /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf ?

If yes, then run (as root) ldconfig to re-read the config.

Comment: Thanks--that was it. I hadn't hand-modified it; `make install` must have done it, and I didn't know about the `ldconfig` command. Appreciate the help!

Comment: It seems that I have to run `sudo ldconfig` every time after installing a new .so in /usr/local/lib.